# Reduce routing avoiding multiplexer

Tags: fpga, verilog, multiplexer

I'm implementing a systolic array for a project, every Processing Element (PE) contains many multiplexers in cascade due to absolute value subtraction and conditional operator, the code looks like something like this:

```
reg[1:0] direction;

localparam [1:0] DIAG  = 2'b00;
localparam [1:0] WEST = 2'b01;
localparam [1:0] NORTH = 2'b10;

assign pixel_up_1   = (pixel_down[23:16]>pixel_up[23:16]) ? pixel_down[23:16] : pixel_up[23:16];
assign pixel_down_1 = (pixel_down[23:16]>pixel_up[23:16]) ? pixel_up[23:16] : pixel_down[23:16];
 ...
assign match = 255 - ( pixel_up_1 - pixel_down_1 );
 ...
assign selector =  (match >= n_wire ? (match >= w_wire ? DIAG : NORTH) : WEST)

always@(posedge CLK) begin
    direction <= selector;
end
```

The problem arise instantiating many PE in the Systolic Array, the routing in the synthesizer is very high and few Flip Flop are used.

I have tried to use pipelined logic for the PEs, more FF are used but the routing doesn't decrease, how can i reduce the combinatory part of the design?

Someone says me to use chip-select logic to avoid mux, but i don't know what it means, any hint?

Comment: Firstly the ```255 - (a - b)``` bit is an obscure way of saying ```~(a-b)```. Depending on how clever the synthesiser is, that will add extra subtraction logic which is unnecessary.

Comment: Now with regards to your absolute subtraction. It's a bit of a long way of doing things. You can actually use the carry out bit of the adder to your advantage: ```assign {carryout,match} = pixel_up[23:16] - pixel_down[23:16]```, now just find the absolute value of ```{carryout,match}```.

Comment: @TomCarpenter: if either of those changes result in a significantly different implementation, it's time to get a new synthesizer ;)

Comment: @Luca: it will be interesting to see if either of Tom's suggestions improve matters for you - can you say which synthesiser you are using?

Comment: @MartinThompson you'd hope it was good enough at optimising, but you never know... :)

Comment: @Tom Carpenter: i have tried your suggestion but there are no significative difference, i'm using Vivado

Comment: `255 - (a - b)` = `255 - a + b` = `(255 - a) + b` = `~a + b`

Comment: already done buddy but no lucky :(